# Is it possible to ask for an Iron Man suit in Jannah?

Tags: allah, jannah

Salam brothers and sisters.
I'm 16 years old, and getting into Islam much more than before. I've been thinking about Jannah specifically as well.

It is mentioned that if we get into Jannah, Inshallah, we'll be given ANYTHING we wish for.

I was wondering, does this include impossible things? Like can I ask for an iron man suit, or can I ask for the superpowers of my favourite TV show?

This may seem childish, and I know Allah has prepared many grand bounties for us, but I want to know if we can request for the impossible.

I'm trying my best to be a good Muslim. For everyone thinking I need to focus more on actually getting into Jannah, I am.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask for impossible or irrational things. However, a suit that enables you to fly is not 'impossible'. It is quite possible and with how technology is advancing (they already have 'jet packs' etc), I even suspect that mankind will end up making those in the near future in the Dunya. But whether technology will be re-established there in Akhirah/Jannah (after everything is destroyed here in the Dunya) is something we will find out when we get there.

That said, Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) confirmed that we would be able to fly around in Paradise. One established method is to be flown around on a ruby horse that takes you where you want to go. The hadith is from Tirmidhi (2544):

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)  said: إن الله أدخلك الجنة فلا تشاء أن تحمل فيها على فرس من ياقوتة حمراء يطير بك في الجنة حيث شئت إلا فعلت (If you are admitted into Paradise, you shall be brought a horse of rubies with two wings, then you shall be carried on it, then it will fly with you wherever you want)."

So you can look forward to flying around in Paradise :)

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the  first answer is really uninformed and misleading , bro you can do whatever you want or wish jhanna you have the power of the mind eyes whatever you wish to see or think you want to have you will inshallah that Allah's SWT prize for us   , and seriously man if you think TV super powers are 'cool ' lol wait till you see jhanna super powers because  ALLAH SWT is pleased and happy with you now you literally cant imagine and will never imagine how those super powers you wish for can be  amplified it is behind your human comprehension just like everything elese jhanna The Verse is Simple:  Kol Ma Tashtahi All Anfous . Anfous coming From Nafs / Nefs  for ex in this life you say  " Ana Nefsi Ateyr " I wish/ want/ need to fly and that's it By ALLAH SWT Graciouses you are already in the air and in a way and speed beyond your human comprehension ;);) and another simple proof in surah Ya Seen Verse :" Lahom feha Fakehah Wa Lahom Ma Yadouun"  What ever dua or wish you want as simple as that  Because of ALLAH SWT graciousness and mercy so put  that in mind :D.

Answer (score 0):

As-salaam Alykum brother. Point of correction please for Allah the most high their is nothing impossible.Even the word impossible itself is a creation of Allah the mighty in power.So In Shaa Allah in jannah whatever that pleases you will be there.All you need to do is just work hard to be there.